# How can I create proc tree in c

Tags: c, process, tree, proc

I have this array of number that tells how many children processes each parent has to make or rather what is the structure of a tree.

For example, if array contains 1 4 0 0 3, then the proc tree looks like this
http://shrani.si/f/S/IW/8HrGEVJ/proctree.jpg

I think it might be solvable with a recursion, but I don't know how to read an array and determine where and how many children procs should I fork. Also, how do you create more children from a one parent if your code template is like this:

```
void recTreeProc(){

    /* create process */
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
            /* error */
            perror("fork failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    else if (pid == 0) {
            /*  child process */
            //call recursion?
    }
    else {
            /* parent process */
            //wait for all the children to execute
            int status;
            (void)waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

    }

}
```

Comment: Your example is insufficient.  The root has one child, that node has 4 children, but why are the 3 children hanging off the third node?  If the next integer in the array were 2, would the 2 children be on the sibling node of the node with 3 children, or would they be descendants?  (It would be easier to talk about the diagram if there were labels!)

Comment: 0 0 3, means that the first and the second node of those four have no descendants, the third one has three

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the code for the implementation of the tree and the array because i didn't get what the values means but for multiple childs you can try that :

```
void recTreeProc() {

  /* create process */
  pid_t pid;
  int n = 0;
  int cpid[CHILD_NB];

  do {
     pid = fork();
     if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     else if (pid) {
        cpid[n];
     }
     n++;
  } while(n < CHILD_NB && pid); // I want CHILD_NB childs
  if (!pid) {
   /* childs */
  }
  else {
        /* parent process */
        //wait for all the children to execute
        int status[CHILD_NB];
        n = 0;
        while (n < CHILD_NB) {
          (void)waitpid(cpid[n], &status[n], 0);
          n++;
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. the numbers mean how many children a parent has. The root has one node, this one has 4 children and the first two have no descendants, the third one has 3 and the fourth has none

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to build it with the array but with a one dimension array its just to messy. Or you need another format like a char * to parse;

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to build it with the array but with a one dimension array its just to messy or you need to have childs really next to the parent and always end by 0 but still. Or you need another format like a char * to parse; "1-4-0|0|3|0" with "-" = child and "|" = bro'
even better a struct
struct s_node { s_node *child, int child_number };